# ACF Data field - output string

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using datapicker with ACF and printing out a data string. Everything so far is fine, but my string look's like " 04022017 ", so its 04 02 2017. Not sure why I'm getting the string like that, but its giving me already formatted data but no slashes between them. I Tried all instructions from Stack etc and nothing works.

Is there is a way that I can put '/' into it between day/month/year?

Comment: Go the field group in that specific field. Look at the "Returned Format". Probably "20170208" format is checked. If yes, change that.

Comment: change into what ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

You are receiving the default date format, store the 'get_field' value in any variable as displayed below:

```
<?php $date_value = get_field('field_name');
echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($date_value)); ?>
```

Comment: When Im using your solution Im getting this effect "01/01/1970" , maybe small additional info. I getting my date from each post like this :  get_field('describe_date', $post_id). Since now none solution helped me.

Comment: Ok, then i think you have not changed the 'date format' field in your custom field in your admin backend. There will two options in the date custom field, one will be 'save Format' & other wil be 'display format'. So, please try by changing the display format & 'save format' value to 'dd/mm/yy' or any other format.

Comment: 'save format' can also be named as 'return format', so don't be confused. So, after changing this format value to 'dd/mm/yy' or in any other format, i think your problem would be solved.

Comment: For more info-> https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/